# Simple antivirus

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a simple antivirus in Python and would love feedback for additional ideas to implement, as well as general code review.

So far it has a `FileScanner` that checks against a database of known virus hashes and a network scanner that checks against a database of potentially malicious IP addresses.

I'm very curious about what I can do to move forward with this project.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import re
import time
import psutil
import hashlib
import sqlite3
import requests
import threading
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from argparse import ArgumentParser


WINDOWS = os.name == 'nt'
if WINDOWS:
    from win10toast import ToastNotifier


class DB(object):
    # TODO: Log the URLS it's grabbed hashes from
    # And check the logged urls and skip over logged urls
    # when calling the self.update() function
    def __init__(self, db_fp='data.db'):
        self.db_fp = db_fp
        self.connect()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.close()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<SQLite3 Database: {}>".format(self.db_fp)

    def connect(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_fp)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def close(self):
        self.conn.commit()
        self.cur.close()
        self.conn.close()

    def create_tables(self):
        self.cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS virus_md5_hashes(md5_hash TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)')
        self.cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS processed_virusshare_urls(url TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)')
        self.cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS high_risk_ips(ip TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)')
        self.conn.commit()

    def drop_tables(self):
        self.cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS virus_md5_hashes')
        self.cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS processed_virusshare_urls')
        self.cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS high_risk_ips')
        self.conn.commit()

    def add(self, table, value):
        try:
            sql = f"INSERT INTO {table} VALUES (?)"
            self.cur.execute(sql, (value,))
        except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
            if 'UNIQUE' in str(e):
                pass # Do nothing if trying to add a duplicate value
            else:
                raise e

    def exists(self, vname, table, value):
        sql = f"SELECT {vname} FROM {table} WHERE {vname} = (?)"
        self.cur.execute(sql, (value,))
        return self.cur.fetchone() is not None

    def reset(self):
        '''
        reformats the database, think of it as a fresh-install
        '''
        # self.drop_tables() # This is soooo slow
        self.close()
        os.remove(self.db_fp)
        self.connect()
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.create_tables()
        self.update_md5_hashes()
        self.update_high_risk_ips()

    def update_md5_hashes(self):
        '''
        updates the sqlite database of known virus md5 hashes
        '''
        urls = self.get_virusshare_urls()
        for n, url in enumerate(urls):
            reprint(f"Downloading known virus hashes {n+1}/{len(urls)}")
            if not self.exists('url', 'processed_virusshare_urls', url):
                for md5_hash in self.get_virusshare_hashes(url):
                    self.add('virus_md5_hashes', md5_hash)
                self.add('processed_virusshare_urls', url)
            self.conn.commit()
        print()

    def get_virusshare_urls(self) -> list:
        '''
        returns a list of virusshare.com urls containing md5 hashes
        '''
        r = requests.get('https://virusshare.com/hashes.4n6')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        return ["https://virusshare.com/{}".format(a['href']) for a in soup.find_all('a')][6:-2]

    def get_virusshare_hashes(self, url) -> str:
        '''
        parses all the md5 hashes from a valid virusshare.com url
        '''
        r = requests.get(url)
        return r.text.splitlines()[6:]

    def update_high_risk_ips(self):
        sources = [
            'https://blocklist.greensnow.co/greensnow.txt',
            'https://cinsscore.com/list/ci-badguys.txt',
            'http://danger.rulez.sk/projects/bruteforceblocker/blist.php',
            'https://malc0de.com/bl/IP_Blacklist.txt',
            'https://rules.emergingthreats.net/blockrules/compromised-ips.txt',
            'https://rules.emergingthreats.net/fwrules/emerging-Block-IPs.txt',
            'https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py?ip=1.1.1.1',
            'https://feodotracker.abuse.ch/blocklist/?download=ipblocklist',
            'https://hosts.ubuntu101.co.za/ips.list',
            'https://lists.blocklist.de/lists/all.txt',
            'https://myip.ms/files/blacklist/general/latest_blacklist.txt',
            'https://pgl.yoyo.org/adservers/iplist.php?format=&showintro=0',
            'https://ransomwaretracker.abuse.ch/downloads/RW_IPBL.txt',
            'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/firehol/blocklist-ipsets/master/stopforumspam_7d.ipset',
            'https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/?exit',
            'https://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/ip.txt',
            'https://www.maxmind.com/es/proxy-detection-sample-list',
            'https://www.projecthoneypot.org/list_of_ips.php?t=d&rss=1',
            'http://www.unsubscore.com/blacklist.txt',
        ]
        for n, source in enumerate(sources):
            reprint(f"Downloading ips list: {n+1}/{len(sources)}")
            try:
                r = requests.get(source)
                for ip in re.findall(r'[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}', r.text):
                    self.add('high_risk_ips', ip)
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
                print(f"Exception at {source}")
        print()


class FileScanner(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._bad_files = []

    def get_files_recursively(self, folder) -> str:
        '''
        :param folder: directory to resursively check for binary files
        :return: generator of all binary files (str == full path)
        '''
        for folder_name, sub_folder, filenames in os.walk(folder):
            for f in filenames:
                f = f"{folder_name}/{f}"
                yield f

    def get_md5(self, fp) -> str:
        '''
        :param fp: full path to a file
        :return: the md5 hash of a file
        '''
        md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
        with open(fp, "rb") as f:
            for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
                md5_hash.update(chunk)
        return md5_hash.hexdigest()

    def compare_against_database(self, fp):
        if is_binary(fp):
            with DB() as db: # db connection has to be called within the same thread accessing the db uhg.jpg
                md5_hash = self.get_md5(fp)
                if db.exists('md5_hash', 'virus_md5_hashes', md5_hash):
                    self._bad_files.append(fp)

    def scan(self, folder, max_threads=10):
        start_time = time.time()
        fp_gen = self.get_files_recursively(folder)
        count = 0
        try:
            while True:
                if threading.active_count() < max_threads:
                    fp = next(fp_gen)
                    t = threading.Thread(target=self.compare_against_database, args=(fp, ))
                    t.start()
                    count += 1
                    s = f'Scanning Files - Threads: {threading.active_count()}    Files Scanned: {count}     '
                    reprint(s)
                else:
                    time.sleep(0.01)
        except OSError:
            print(f"OSError: Bad file descriptor: {fp} {' ' * len(fp)}")
        except StopIteration:
            end_time = time.time()
            reprint(' ' * len(s))
            print(f"scanned {count} files in {round(end_time - start_time, 2)} seconds")
            for f in self._bad_files:
                print(f"INFECTED - {f}")


class NetworkScanner(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, timer=1):
        self._timer = timer
        self._running = True
        self.update_current_connections()
        self._displayed_notifications = []
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def update_current_connections(self):
        self._current_connections = psutil.net_connections()

    def scan(self):
        with DB() as db:
            for conn in self._current_connections:
                if conn.status != "NONE" or conn.status != "CLOSE_WAIT":
                    if db.exists('ip', 'high_risk_ips', conn.laddr.ip):
                        self.notify(conn.laddr.ip, conn.laddr.port, conn.pid)
                    if conn.raddr:
                        if db.exists('ip', 'high_risk_ips', conn.raddr.ip):
                            self.notify(conn.raddr.ip, conn.raddr.port, conn.pid)

    def notify(self, ip, port, pid, duration=10):
        title, body = "High Risk Connection", f"{psutil.Process(pid).name()}\n{ip}:{port} - {pid}"
        if body not in self._displayed_notifications:
            if WINDOWS:
                ToastNotifier().show_toast(title, body, duration=duration, threaded=True)
                self._displayed_notifications.append(body)
            else:
                print("{} {}".format(title, body))
                self._displayed_notifications.append(body)

    def run(self):
        print('[+] Network Scanner Initialized')
        while self._running:
            self.update_current_connections()
            self.scan()
            time.sleep(self._timer)

    def stop(self):
        print('[-] Network Scanner Stopping')
        self._running = False


def is_binary(fp, chunksize=1024) -> bool:
    """Return true if the given filename is binary.
    @raise EnvironmentError: if the file does not exist or cannot be accessed.
    @attention: found @ http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/21222-determine-file-type-binary-text on 6/08/2010
    @author: Trent Mick <TrentM@ActiveState.com>
    @author: Jorge Orpinel <jorge@orpinel.com>"""
    try:
        with open(fp, 'rb') as f:
            while True:
                chunk = f.read(chunksize)
                if b'\0' in chunk: # found null byte
                    return True
                if len(chunk) < chunksize:
                    break
    except PermissionError:
        print(f"Permission Error: {fp} {' ' * len(fp)}")
    return False

def reprint(s):
    print(s, end='')
    print('\r' * len(s), end='')

def parse_args():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('path', default=os.getcwd(), type=str, help="path to scan")
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--update', action="store_true", default=False, help="updates database of virus definitions & high risk IP's")
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--threads', default=20, type=int, help="max threads for file scanner")
    return parser.parse_args()


def Main():
    # Testing for now
    args = parse_args()
    if args.update:
        with DB() as db:
            print('[+] Updating database')
            db.update()
    nsc = NetworkScanner()
    nsc.start()
    FileScanner().scan(args.path, args.threads)
    nsc.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick performance boost for your database is to use the fact that you can insert multiple rows at the same time. Which you can use in your code both for the IPs and for the hashes, so this can be quite useful:

```
def add_multiple(self, table, values):
    sql = f"INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {table} VALUES (?)"
    self.cur.executemany(sql, [(value,) for value in values])
```

Note that I used `INSERT OR IGNORE` to ignore already existing rows. **Beware that this command is susceptible to SQL-injection**, because a malicious value for `table` can do anything in this command (same as in yours). In this case it should be fairly easy to avoid this, since you know all legal table names, so just whitelist them explicitly.

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    ...
    self.tables = {"virus_md5_hashes",
                   "processed_virusshare_urls",
                   "high_risk_ips"}

def add(self, table, value):
    if table not in self.tables:
        raise ValueError("This table does not exist")
    sql = f"INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {table} VALUES (?)"
    self.cur.execute(sql, (value,))

def add_multiple(self, table, values):
    if table not in self.tables:
        raise ValueError("This table does not exist")
    sql = f"INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {table} VALUES (?)"
    self.cur.executemany(sql, [(value,) for value in values])
```

Your update functions need to be only slightly modified for the multiple insert to work:

```
def update_md5_hashes(self):
    '''
    updates the sqlite database of known virus md5 hashes
    '''
    for n, url in enumerate(self.virusshare_urls):
        reprint(f"Downloading known virus hashes {n+1}/{len(urls)}")
        if not self.exists('url', 'processed_virusshare_urls', url):
            self.add_multiple('virus_md5_hashes', self.get_virusshare_hashes(url))
            self.add('processed_virusshare_urls', url)
            self.conn.commit()
    print()

IP_ADDRESS = re.compile(r'[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}')

def update_high_risk_ips(self):
    for n, source in enumerate(self.ip_blacklists):
        reprint(f"Downloading ips list: {n+1}/{len(sources)}")
        try: 
            r = requests.get(source)
            self.add_many('high_risk_ips', IP_ADDRESS.findall(r.text))
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
            print(f"Exception at {source}")
    print()
```

I would also put your virusshare URLs and blacklisted IP sources as an attribute of the class so you can change it at runtime, if needed. You can also make them properties if you don't like them being changed, but want to have them accessible nevertheless.

Note that in the first function you do have a `self.conn.commit` (which I moved under the `if`, no need for a commit if you didn't do anything), but not in the latter. This could be a bug.